# Plotting TV series through time: scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

have this dataset

```
ID  TV            Start
55  gameofthrones   21:34:00
20  beverlyhills    21:34:00
66  modernfamiily   00:34:00
65  housemd         01:34:00
69  hunters         01:34:00
... ... ...
65  housemd         16:34:00
38  mrroobot        16:34:00
```

I need to plot TV Series in ascending order, from 00:00 to 23:59, based on Start (time). 
I have tried as follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.figure()
plt.plot(df['TV'],df['Start'])
```

and it works. However, I would like to consider a scatter plot, as sometimes lines overlaps to each other, making difficult to visualise the order. 
How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert the values of `Start` column into datetime, then sort the dataframe using this column:

```
# sorting the dataframe by the start time
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
df = df.sort_values(by='Time').drop('Time', 1)

# Drawing the sample Scatter plot
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(df['Start'], df['TV'], s=100)
plt.show()
```

---

```
# Dataframe after sorting by Time:
# print(df)

 ID             TV     Start
 66  modernfamiily  00:34:00
 65        housemd  01:34:00
 69        hunters  01:34:00
 65        housemd  16:34:00
 38       mrroobot  16:34:00
 55  gameofthrones  21:34:00
 20   beverlyhills  21:34:00
```

Example, Scatter plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Shubham Sharma. Unfortunately I am getting this error: `TypeError: invalid type promotion` Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: @Math Can you show me the stack trace where the error has occurred?

Comment: Yes, sure. `TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-dcddf551bdb8> in <module>
      1 plt.figure()
----> 2 plt.scatter(df['Start'], df['TV'], s=100) -> 2816         None else {}), **kwargs)

`

Comment: @Math Well the code is working fine on my machine, Can you try `plt.scatter(df['Start'].tolist(), df['TV'].tolist(), s=100)`?

Comment: I am getting this error: `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timedelta'`

Comment: @Math What's the dtype of `Start` in your orignal dataframe? You can check it by `df['Start'].dtype`.

Comment: It is dtype(‘<m8[ns]’)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215677/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-math).